Select all rows from one table but join rows based on date range
I have the following tables: shops and orders.
I need to select all shops assigned to a specific user, but only get the orders between a specific date range, im trying to do this in one query but cant seem to get it correct.
For example, I want all of Alans assigned shops, so I will do something like the following:
SELECT s.shop_id, 
       s.shop_name, 
       u.first_name as agent_name 
FROM shops s 
JOIN users u ON u.id = s.user_id 
WHERE s.user_id = 123;

I then need all that shops orders, so I can then join on the orders table like so:
SELECT s.id as shop_id, 
       s.shop_name, 
       u.name as agent_name, 
       count(o.shop_id) 
FROM shops s 
JOIN users u ON u.id = s.user_id 
JOIN orders o ON o.shop_id = s.id 
WHERE s.user_id = 123;

However, my predicament is that i only want to bring back the orders within a partular time frame, bearing in mind that some shops may not have orders in the timeframe so selecting from the orders table and joining the shop will not always be correct.
Any help is greatly appreciated!
EDIT:
The table structure is as follows:
SHOPS



id
shop_name
user_id




1
Test Shop
1



ORDERS



id
items
created_at




1
pizza
2024-10-10 13:15:28



USERS



id
name




1
Josh



This expected result if a date of 2024-10-11 would be:



shop_id
shop_name
first_name
order_count




1
Test shop
Josh
0



This expected result if a date of 2024-10-10 would be:



shop_id
shop_name
first_name
order_count




1
Test shop
Josh
1




Please provide some sample data of the affected tables and the expected result

I.e. give us a [mcve].

I have added the table structure now, thanks

You'll need a LEFT JOIN instead of the default INNER JOIN, or shops with no orders would be excluded.

You need a LEFT JOIN instead of just JOIN (INNER JOIN) to the orders table, or it would exclude the entire row from the results if there are no matching orders at all. In my own code, I never just write JOIN by itself, and instead always pair it with another keyword to disambiguate what I want: INNER, LEFT, RIGHT, FULL, or CROSS.
You also need to GROUP BY the main columns, so you can count the orders within that group. I further suspect, but am not certain, you would also want to group by the date of the created_at column (or a related calendar table/projection), but there's not enough information in the question to include that as part of this answer.
For the date filter, I'll proceed using date or datetime as the data type for the created_at column, and provide an @target_date variable of the same type as the input.
SELECT s.id as shop_id, 
       s.shop_name, 
       u.name as agent_name, 
       count(o.id) 
FROM shops s 
INNER JOIN users u ON u.id = s.user_id 
LEFT JOIN orders o ON o.shop_id = s.id 
    AND o.created_at >= @target_date AND o.created_at < date_add(@target_date, interval 1 day)
WHERE s.user_id = 123
GROUP BY s.id, s.shop_name, u.name

Note how I built the range. You could use a BETWEEN for this, or for a single day ensure both sides have no time component and do a direct equality comparison. That would even be better if you know your column is already a date value instead of datetime. But that information is not included with the question, and in the face of any doubt on matter I've found half-open range comparisons like this, with an exclusive upper bound for the day after the range, tend to work better for dates.
